# Excel How can i substitute labels of named ranges to access their values in a formula

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have an excel sheet.

Defined the following as a named range

```
Sheet1: Range Name = "Complexity"

Complexity  Hrs
---------------
Minor       4
Simple      12
Medium      30
Complex     48
```

I need the following substitution from the named range such that, I get the number for the labels.

```
Sheet2 
====================================
Complexity    Hrs 
Simple        =(Complexity(Simple))
...
...
Complex       =(Complexity(Complex))
```

Such that the result should look like

```
Sheet2 
====================================
Complexity    Hrs 
Simple        12
...
...
Complex       48
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Complexity,2,False)
```

Comment: How can i use the formula on empty cells?. with the proposed formula, i am getting "#NA" if A2 is an empty cell. thanks!

Comment: Wrap in IFERROR(): `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Complexity,2,False),"")`